# Is it wise to build an MVC app around a RESTful API using nothing but HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, architecture

My boss wants a full REST API for our new project. But, he also wants a UI for it and our deadline is not very generous. Learning a decent front-end framework (Angular, React, Vue) might prove to take a little too long.

He is asking if we could talk to the REST API using MVC entirely. I explained to him that MVC means the view is tightly coupled to the controller.

He asked why we cannot just build out the REST API fully, and then make an MVC app that uses `HttpClient` in the controller (or a service class) to hit the API.Is that a bad idea? I told him it seemed like another big layer to maintain and that most people are probably using a nice front-end framework to talk to their back-end.

I also felt like I did not know enough about how other people handle this situation. So those of you that **MUST** have a REST API for all new apps. How do you build your UI for it? We are using Swagger, so generating TypeScript or C# clients is possible if that helps.

Comment: So he wants REST API but the only thing that will call that api will be your MVC controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Learning a decent front-end framework (Angular, React, Vue) might
>   prove to take a little too long.

MVC is a decent front-end framework.  Do you disagree?

> He is asking if we could talk to the REST API using MVC entirely. I
>   explained to him that MVC means the view is tightly coupled to the
>   controller.

He's right and MVC doesn't tightly-couple you to anything.  Bad programming tightly-couples.

> He asked why we cannot just build out the REST API fully, and then
>   make an MVC app that uses HttpClient in the controller (or a service
>   class) to hit the API.Is that a bad idea?

MVC to API is very common.  Like your boss said, you have your MVC (UI Layer) controller connect to your API using an HttpClient instance.  He's got it nailed here.

What your boss is describing is a very common thing in the Microsoft stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is really helpful. I see things out there like this: https://github.com/gothinkster/realworld and I don't see any Core MVC apps for their UI. Also Googling my question in a variety of ways did not yield many tutorials or examples on consuming a REST API entirely in MVC. Most of them teach building hybrid MVC/REST API apps. It seems like many people will consume their REST APIs with modern JS apps. But if time to market is important, and this is more or less a huge CRUD app, MVC might be the best tool for the job.

Comment: By MVC to API you mean you implement rest api and then call it from controller? But what's a point doing that, why not just call that rest api directly from web page?

Comment: @Evk...Page calls MVC controller and that calls API controller.  Of course he can call the API from a web page, but there may be reasons to route it through an MVC controller.

Comment: @VictorioBerra...the trend is definitely towards JS Apps calling directly to APIs, but MVC to API is still a good way to do it.  Pick the tool for the job.

Comment: Correct. @Evk that is the essence of my question. Angular vs MVC (using HttpClient inside a Controller). More specifically, is the later normal, and common. I have been doing web apps for a long time but I never saw myself (or anyone else) separating my MVC app from its data layer and connecting it via HTTP on the back-end.

Comment: I don't see a MVC vs Angular.  MVC can do a *lot of stuff* that you don't need with Angular.  But it's still advantageous to use MVC for templating security etc IMHO.  Just because you don't use MVC for data-bind html server side doesn't mean you have to throw away everything else it can do.

Answer (score 3):

> He is asking if we could talk to the REST API using MVC entirely.

Yes this is very common.  The current version of MVC [asp.net-core-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc) is basically [MVC/WebApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) wrapped into one *Framework*.

> I explained to him that MVC means the view is tightly coupled to the controller.

**No**.  The controller really has nothing to do with anything other than building a model and routing to a view.  *Every* project I've built from scratch, the view has no knowledge of the controller and most of the time is only aware of a model being passed to it (other times there isn't even a model).  Someone *could* tightly couple the view to the controller, but I would not recommend that.

> He asked why we cannot just build out the REST API fully,

You can, it's very easy, I do it almost all of the time.

> make an MVC app that uses HttpClient in the controller (or a service class) to hit the API.

That is a *bad idea* **if** they are the same project.  There is no good reason to add another network layer.  It doesn't provide any value.

> I also felt like I did not know enough about how other people handle this situation

So this is really my personal opinion.  I've worked with Asp.net-mvc since version 2.0 with jQuery.  I moved onto using MVC with [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) which moved 95% of the data into API calls and most of my views don't have models.  I've worked on projects with Angular, but based on my very limited knowledge, it was much harder to pickup and seemed to require much more to get something simple done.  I'm currently working with Kendo (similar to Knockout MVVM) and it does the job.  In all these instances with front end Javascript Frameworks, most of my views are model-less, relying exclusively on API.

If I were to start a new project with limited time, IMHO MVC/WebAPI + Knockout is ridiculously easy.  Again this is just my opinion based on my preferences and experiences.

**HOWEVER**  *warning: rant*

*Why does he want it as a REST Api?*  Seriously, I really loath when any type of manager tells me what tools I should use to build a solution.  It's the new/old SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) of our time.  Sometimes adding a requirement with no reason just adds more time/resources to get a solution out the door.

For example:

Manager: I have a need to deliver a pallet to a destination.  Create a vehicle that can carry one pallet to the destination as efficiently as possible.  Oh and it needs 4 doors!

Me: Why the *f* does it need four doors?  Because you like 4 doors?  Because it's the new craze?

Comment: Doesn't the controller need to build out a ViewModel that is highly specific and designed specifically for a single view? It seems to me that the controller is tightly connected to its view. The JSON API is neede so outher departments can CRUD the apps data. Its not just a knee-jerk architecture decision.

Comment: Don't confuse data flow with a dependency.  I can create a person view that depends on a person class.  What controller creates that person class doesn't matter.  For reasons of [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) I would only create a single `PersonController` but thats for architectural reasons, not any type of requirement based on tightly coupling.

Comment: Also *back in the day* (like 2008) before I was using knockout, my MVC code could return a view or the views model as Json.  So a user would goto the page and it would load the MVC View with the data, and when someone would hit next or whatever, I'd just download the JSON and update the view without a page reload.

Comment: Yes, we have done this with Angular 1.x. Serialize the @model to JSON and then write it wrap to the page in a script tag. Then Angular could pick it up. This is a nice option for adding some JS functionality to a stateless MVC app.

Comment: Well if you've done Angular, Use MVC to deliver Html and REST data..  Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: That doesn't really relate to the issue, which is obtaining said REST data server side (`HttpClient`) instead of client side(`@angular/common/http`).

Answer (score 0):

> My boss wants a full REST API for our new project. But, he also wants a UI for it and our deadline is not very generous.

If you use HTML as your media type, you'll be able to use any web browser you like to render the UI.

Some of the json hypermedia formats may also have browsers; for example [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) author Mike Kelly has a github project for a [browser](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser).

Answer (score 0):

If your backend is in a relational database and indeed your deadline is tight, here's an alternative to coding the API endopoints by hand. Take a look at SlashDB, which wraps database in an intuitive API for reading and writing and provides a GUI in HTML too. In also has an SDK for AngularJS and is generally easy to use for any web/mobile app in any framework.

https://slashdb.com

This may just buy you enough time to perfect the web-app in the framework of your choosing rather than put that time into data access code, which often will be "invisible" to users.

Disclaimer: SlashDB is a product of my company.

Comment: Now that is a really cool product. Writing CRUD apps should be fully automated like that in 2018. The DB design should take all the time and hard work.